# Create single View for all CRUD operations in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new in MVC.Want to apply simple CRUD operation using single View.I don't want separate views such as Create,Edit,Delete,Read.I am using Entity framework by code first approach.

1. I want Text boxes to input data.
2. Grid View which shows all information about particular master.
3. buttons to perform operations(Add,Update,Delete).

I have tried for following code.please help me to work this out....

```
    @model IEnumerable<WareHouse.WareHouseType>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
        WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model);
    }
    @using(Html.BeginForm) {
    <div class="tdhdr1" >Warehouse Type Details
            </div>


    @grid.GetHtml( fillEmptyRows: true,
        alternatingRowStyle: "alternative-row",
        headerStyle: "tdhdr2",

        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
        firstText: "<< First",
        previousText: "< Previous", nextText: "Next >",
        lastText: "Last >>",columns: new [] {
        grid.Column("WareHouseTypeID",header: "ID", canSort: false),
        grid.Column("WareHouseTypeName",header:"Name ")
    })
    }
```

above code only for gridview.
I want other controls also on same View.Is it possible by using Partial View?
I cant add **Editorfor().** on same view.

But it throws error  ** The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WareHouse.WareHouseType]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'WareHouse.WareHouseType'. **

Partial View Code

```
@model WareHouse.WareHouseType

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>AddProduct</title>    
</head>
<body>
    <div>      
           <label>Id:</label>
            @Html.TextBox("Id", Model.WareHouseTypeID)
             <label>Name:</label>
            @Html.TextBox("Name", Model.WareHouseTypeName)

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

General View Code  :

```
    @model IEnumerable<WareHouse.WareHouseType>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
        WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model);
    }

    @using(Html.BeginForm()) {
    <div class="tdhdr1" >Warehouse Type Detailsdfgdgfdgdfg
            </div>

        @Html.Partial("_WHT")
        @grid.GetHtml( fillEmptyRows: true,
        alternatingRowStyle: "alternative-row",
        headerStyle: "tdhdr2",

        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
        firstText: "<< First",
        previousText: "< Previous", nextText: "Next >",
        lastText: "Last >>",columns: new [] {
        grid.Column("WareHouseTypeID",header: "ID", canSort: false),
        grid.Column("WareHouseTypeName",header:"Name dfgsdfsdf")
    })
    }
```

controller code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WareHouse;

namespace CommonMasterUI.Controllers
{
    public class WHTypeController : Controller
    {


              WareHouse.Context ctx = new WareHouse.Context();
        IList<WareHouseType> list2 = new List<WareHouseType>();
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IList<WareHouseType> wht = new List<WareHouseType>();  
            WareHouseRepository wr = new WareHouseRepository(ctx);
            wht = wr.GetWareHouseTP().ToList();


            for (int i = 0; i < wht.Count; i++)
            {
                WareHouseType wt = new WareHouseType();

                wt.WareHouseTypeID = wht.ElementAt(i).WareHouseTypeID;
                wt.WareHouseTypeName = wht.ElementAt(0).WareHouseTypeName.ToString();
                list2.Add(wt);

            }


            return View(list2.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!Can you share sample code for this...

Comment: Might be duplicate of this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168030/asp-net-mvc-single-view-for-crud-operation.

Verify above link, and let us know if it doesn't full fill your requirements.

Comment: I have already gone through above solution.Now I have created partial view for Text boxes

Comment: Great, if you still have any issues then do post proper code.

Comment: `But it throws error ** The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WareHouse.WareHouseType]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'WareHouse.WareHouseType'. **` At some point you are calling the view with a single entity and not an array which it is expecting, can you post the controller code?